# How to create a dynamic radio button in grails controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, gsp

Currently I am working with grails and MySQL.

I have to create a dynamic radio button in the controller and pass to the view. How can I do this?

For example:
 radio button with 
yes or no 
 and
male or female

These values are now in the database. Now my problem is how can I create the radio button in the controller and pass it to the grails view?

```
List queryData
String s="";
for(int i=0;i<eventformAttri.size();i++){
    queryData=formField.masterTableQuery(eventformAttri[i].fieldQuery.toString()) //to fetch the radio buttons values
    for(int ii=0;ii<queryData.size();ii++){
        System.out.println("list data "+queryData[ii].field1)
        s+=queryData[ii].field1+" <input type='radio' name='myGroup"+i+"' value="+queryData[ii].field2+" />";
    }
    s+=",";
}
def vformData=s.split(',');
render(view:'/auditor/formView',model:[eventformAttri:eventformAttri,queryData:vformData])
```

Comment: I wondering how you can create a radio button in the controller.
I think in the controller, you can "process" data as pass it to the defined radio button in grails view.

Comment: my current situation is to create radio button dynamically..now i have the value in controller queryData[ii].field1,but i cant get it from view .

Answer (score 1):

You should create your radio button in your view, and use the embedded jquery library to do that. For instance, combine your jquery script in the view with a remotelink to interact with your controller:

```
$('input:radio[title=YOUR TITLE]').attr('checked',true);


    <g:remoteLink controller="yourcontroller" action="youraction" update="[success: 'results']" onSuccess="yourFunction(data) ">Your link</g:remoteLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating what Phat H. VU is saying, through the controller, send `queryData` as is,

```
render(view:'/auditor/formView',model:[queryData:queryData])
```

and use the view to render the info,

```
<g:radioGroup name="dynaRad"
              labels="${queryData.collect{it.field1}}"
              values="${queryData.collect{it.field2}}">
    <p>${it.label} ${it.radio}</p>
</g:radioGroup>
```